# Difference between use of %%A and %A%

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dos

I have the following script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4" %%A IN ("REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\") DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

However if we change **ECHO %%A** to:

```
ECHO %A%
```

The output is the same.

Normally in batch scripts I echo my variables with **%A%**, what is the difference and why do people sometimes use **%%A** as appose to **%A%**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases, two reasons:

- The doubled `%` is the documented way to use a temporary variable, e.g., for the `for` loop, in a batch file (not on the command-line).
- Putting `%` on each side of a variable is [documented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/75634) as the way to expand an environment variable.

Presumably your loop just happens to work because the temporary variable is visible in the same tables as environment variables - but like variables within the scope of `setlocal`, it goes away.

MSDN documents both in [kb75634](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/75634), *Percent Signs Stripped from Batch File Text*